# javascript to format json string in .net view

Tags: javascript, .net, json.net

[image]so i'm using the below js to take a json string and format it to display it in the table view...
the problem is that for some reason...

```
var obj = JSON.parse(@item.requestExample)
```

is throwing a reference error at execution...

```
                @foreach (var item in Model.list)
                {
            <tr class="table-info">
                <td>@item.library</td>
                <td>@item.api</td>
                <td>@item.ibmiPgm</td>
                <td>@item.requestExample</td>
                <td>
                    <p id="GFG_UP" style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;"></p>

                    <pre id="GFG_DOWN" style="color:green; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;"></pre>

                    <script>
                        var el_up = document.getElementById("GFG_UP");
                        var el_down = document.getElementById("GFG_DOWN");
                        var obj = JSON.parse(@item.requestExample);

                        el_up.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);

                        function gfg_Run() {
                            el_down.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4);
                        }
                    </script>

                </td>


                <td>
                    <button typeof="button" onclick="gfg_Run();">Format JSON</button>
                    <button typeof="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(item.api, "", new { api = item.api, jsonRequest = item.requestExample } )'">Consume API</button>
                </td>
```

the raw string is:  {"env":"xxx","command":"getCustomerBankAccountInfo","payload":[{"custNo":"101"},{"custNo":"102"}]}

and when the "format json" is clicked at runtime, the inspect/console shows there is an unexpected token & in my string...

```
       var obj = JSON.parse({&quot;env&quot;:&quot;xxx&quot;,&quot;command&quot;:&quot;getTableLayout&quot;,&quot;payload&quot;:[{&quot;schema&quot;:&quot;COREIRST&quot;,&quot;table&quot;:&quot;RST00001T&quot;},{&quot;schema&quot;:&quot;COREIRST&quot;,&quot;table&quot;:&quot;RST00002T&quot;}]});
```

Hopefully someone can tell me what I am missing here...

tia

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse()` will not replace html characters for you. You would need to replace all of your `&quot;`s with actual `"` characters.

Comment: it does not work... any time i even reference the @item.requestExample (json string) in my js it errors withe the unexpected token of the &quot;

Comment: A couple things - in your last code snippet, `JSON.parse` accepts a string parameter, you would need to wrap in single or double quotes. Also, if you need to handle the `&quot;`s with javascript it is simple to replace them, but I would recommend looking for a solution in your backend code because you won't want to have to handle all possible html characters in your js. That said, here's how you would replace with js: `dataString.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');`

Comment: this was totally the wrong approach and just so you know, the best method is...``` <td>
        <pre>@Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse(item.requestExample).ToString()</pre>
    </td>```

Answer (score 0):

.Net is trying to sanitize your input for you. Simply wrap your call with the HTML decoder in .Net.

```
var obj = JSON.parse('@(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@item.requestExample))');
```

<sub>Note: I wrap this with an extra set of parenthesis because Razor gets weird when you mix JS/C#</sub>

This will do all the proper replacements @redouglas mentioned with out writing that insane amount of code.

Comment: Both appreciated responses. Thanks. I also had an idea (based on your answers) to somehow access that json request example directly from the model instead of the html @item.requestExample... not sure if that would work but possibly another option. Thank you guys!

Comment: when I put ```var obj = JSON.parse('@(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@item.requestExample))');``` in my JS script in my .net view it says "the name HttpUtility does not exist in the current context"... any suggestions?

Comment: Paven disregard that, once I qualified it with System.Web it accepted it... however still doesn't seem to work... at runtime in inspect/console... ```localhost/:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at (index):93```  and a look at that shows... ``` var obj = JSON.parse('{&quot;env&quot;:&quot;xxx&quot;,&quot;command&quot;:&quot;getTableLayout&quot;,&quot;payload&quot;...```

Comment: so it does not work... any time i even reference the @item.requestExample (json string) in my js it errors with the unexpected token of the &quot;

Comment: this was totally the wrong approach and just so you know, the best method is...``` <td> <pre>@Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse(item.requestExample).ToString()</pre> </td>``

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution that works, I don't have your full setup, but the minor example I had made was working for me,

Answer (score 0):

this was totally the wrong approach and just so you know, the best method is...
`<td> <pre>@Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse(item.requestExample).ToString()</pre> </td>`